# Inserting into an SQL database?

Tags: mysql

I know this sounds like a very basic question but i've been doing SQl for a little while now and only ever come across this once and its just blowing my mind.

I have a DB called stud with 6 columns.

```
sid     , firstname,lastname   ,title,dob     , gender
"124084","Bobby"   ,"Carpenter","Mr" ,"040774","m"
"129002","Robin"   ,"Hart"     ,"Ms" ,"160275","f"
"129275","Julia"   ,"Foster"   ,"Ms" ,"080575","f"
```

I'm trying to insert it in stud but am getting the

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

```
 INSERT INTO stud ( "123969","Heather","Howard","Ms","111274","f"
 "124084","Bobby","Carpenter","Mr","040774","m"
 "129002","Robin","Hart","Ms","160275","f"
```

is this because the data doesnt have an extra comma after the sex part or?

Sorry for such a noob question but its just been one of them days.

Comment: `INSERT INTO stud VALUES ( ... )` . Before values, it expects the columns (which you should always give, it's a good practice). You need one insert per line.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. so like INSERT INTO stud (sid,firstname....) VALUES (....)?

Comment: Yes, it's a better practice, because if your table changes, your query will still mostly work. Without the columns, it can damage the table because the data is not inserted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to identify the rows

```
INSERT INTO stud (sid, firstname, lastname, title, dob, gender)   
values ("123969","Heather","Howard","Ms","111274","f")
     , ("124084","Bobby","Carpenter","Mr","040774","m")
     , ("129002","Robin","Hart","Ms","160275","f")
```

Comment: the text file i have has a lot of data to be inputted.. is there a quick way i can add these parentheses at the end?

Comment: I suggest you verify this syntax works and then post another question.

Comment: do you need to load data from the file?
if yes, check this post
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33696855/5309594

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify rows and use single quotes, not double. Double quotes interpreted not as strings, but as identifiers, such as table/column name.

```
INSERT INTO stud (sid, firstname, lastname, title, dob, gender)   
values ('123969','Heather','Howard','Ms','111274','f')
     , ('124084','Bobby','Carpenter','Mr','040774','m')
     , ('129002','Robin','Hart','Ms','160275','f')
```